# Setting up IntelliJ IDEA IDE to work with a Play2 application?

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I want to setup IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE for a Play2 application. According to the documentation there should be an idea command that comes with the play framework. See here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/IDE. I just downloaded, unzipped and setup the play framework and even created a new application but the *idea* command seems to be missing.

Where is this command? If it's not going to be available then I could use some tips on setting up the environment manually.

I already tried Creating an new project and importing the sources but IntelliJ did not detect any **frameworks**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to switch to the application folder.

not working:

```
$ play new my-app 
$ play idea
```

output:

```
play! 2.0.3, http://www.playframework.org
This is not a play application!
```

correct:

```
$ play new my-app
$ cd my-app
$ play idea
```

If that does not work, please show what you have typed and what is the output.

IntelliJ IDEA 11 has no native support for play 2.

Comment: My mistake. I was trying to execute idea from the bash shell. I expected idea to be a script in the play installation. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

I follow the steps

1. play new myproject
2. cd myproject
3. play idea

And then following the intellij documentation I tried to import the play module, didnt work

But checking the [Play wiki](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/IDE) I realize that instead of importing the module into an existing project of iltellij I must **open the project** and everithing is already in place.

Answer (score 1):

For Play 2.0, I ran into issues with the vanilla `play idea` command. Most, if not all associated libraries were malformed in the .iml file.

As a workaround, I used `play eclipsify` and used Idea's 'Import from External Source' to create a proper idea project with all the dependencies. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I ran into similar issues with Play 2.0.0.  More recent releases cooperate much better with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using:

```
play idea with-sources=yes
```

Works for me.